# How to measure the quality of fakes produced by a digital twin?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, loss-functions, gan

I have asked this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666437/how-to-evaluate-the-quality-of-a-fake), but it was considered too broad, perhaps because there is no specific code involved. I hope this question is more appropriate for crossvalidated.

I am developing a digital twin for a certain application. The digital twin has parameters that I tried to optimize using cross-entropy of a classifier trained to distinguish real from fake data. The whole setup runs similarly to GAN, except that the generative part is not a NN. Basically, for each iteration of the generative parameter optimization I construct and train the classifier NN, and use the trained classifier validation cross-entropy loss as the indicator of the generator's quality.

I ran into the problem that the classifier cross-entropy loss doesn't seem to be monotone with respect to the quality of the fake. I proved that by freezing the generator and running the classifier training 100 times; the 100 classifiers, trained on the identical inputs, produced widely different validation cross-entropy and accuracy. That makes either cross-entropy or accuracy completely unsuitable for evaluating the quality of the fake: the noise-to-signal ratio is way too high to optimize generative parameters based on the classifier response.

The question is, how do I overcome this problem? How does one produce a measure of fakeness that is sufficiently stable and nearly monotone with respect to the quality of the fake?

Comment: Can you add some details to your question? What is a digital twin? So you have a generator $x=G(z|\theta)$ that is *not* a neural network, but which you want to parameter optimize using a trained classifier $D(x|\phi)=p_\phi(\text{real}|x)$? What is $x$? Do you do what GANs usually do and do alternating optimization (take a few steps for $\theta$ and $\phi$ each)? Or do you train $D$ to convergence before *every* parameter update to $\theta$? Also, how familiar are you with the GAN literature?

Comment: One thing that's not clear to me is whether you are taking advantage of the fact that (for NNs) $\partial_x D(x|\phi)$ is readily computable. If you don't use this, then you are basically doing reinforcement learning with reward $R=D(x|\phi)$! Also, it is well known in GANs that over-training the critic (when using the Jensen-Shannon divergence formulation) leads to totally uninformative signals to the generator.